# Phonegap continuously moving html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, cordova

I am making a bike race game in javascript using the HTML5 canvas.
The game is made up of three canvases: one for background, one for the level and **a small moving canvas(only moving up/down on the y-axis) for the bike**.

This third canvas is constantly moving depending on the position of the bike. To keep from moving the bike canvas too rapidly, I only move it when the bike has moved a substantial distance.

```
if(newBikePos - oldBikePos > 20 || newBikePos - oldBikePos < -20) {
    newBikePos = ((chassis.body.getPos().y + leftWheel.body.getPos().y +
        rightWheel.body.getPos().y)/3 - 150); // Roughly the position of the bike

    gameCanvas.style.top = newBikePos * SCALE; // This is how I move the canvas
}

gameContext.clearRect(0, 0, gameCanvas.width, gameCanvas.height);

// Drawing the bike(chassis, leftwheel and rightwheel) onto the bike canvas
```

Now when I run this on my Mac it´s working just fine(chrome, firefox, safari), but when I run it on my Nexus 4 using Phonegap the canvas is not being cleared properly. Each time the canvas moves, the bike is moving smoothly in the newly positioned canvas, but a "still picture" of the bike from the last frame before the canvas moved is also shown. This "still picture" disappears when the canvas once again changes positions but then a new still is created as described.

Even if I update the canvas at 60 frames per second, the "still picture" will still show, only not as apparent.

Has anyone else run into this problem using Phonegap? Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: It's obviously a DOM rendering problem. Don't know why or how to solve it while keeping your canvas intact but if you use a larger canvas, with the same height of the other layers and use `drawImage` to draw the bike and `clearRect` before it change you can get rid of this error.